# How can I open the previous page in a new tab in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any option to open the previous page in Google Chrome (using the "back" button) in a new window? It should be easy to do something like this, I haven't found any way to do this yet.

Answer (score 10):

To open the previous page in a new tab, all you need to do is middle-click the back button in the upper left hand of the window.

You can also do this with the forward button, the home button, and pretty much any link on any web page.

Comment: great. I don't have a middle button though.

Answer (score 2):

I think what the OP wants to do can be done by holding the CTRL button and clicking on the back button on the top left corner.

Comment: Strange that this seems clearly the best answer, yet it's outvoted by multiple others.

Answer (score 1):

To open the previous page in a new tab, right-click on the tab you want to open, select "duplicate", and then click the back button on the new duplicate tab.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcut sequence would be

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, and then
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

An autohotkey script could look like this (in this example shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
    ^+h::
        SendInput +!T
        SendInput ^+{Enter}
    return
#IfWinActiv
```

Comment: This [suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1132582) states that the `Shift` in `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` is not required... However, that differs from what the code states.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by shortcut, there is no simple way. 
But you can press Alt, hit D, than Enter (with Alt pressed), relase Alt and hit Backspace (it looks little complicated, but in fact is very simple and fast).
It will duplicate your currently tab and load the previous page on it.